# ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the schema with primary key and sort key

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-dynamodb

Using "aws-sdk": "^2.1063.0"  and nodejs 12

Inside my lambda I am doing an update to a dynamodb table.

My table has a Primary key: JobUID type string and a Sort key type string.

[image: From AWS]

My parameters look like this:

```
    var params = {
      TableName: tableName,
      Key: {
        "JobUID": payload.JobUID,
        "TimeStamp": payload.TimeStamp
      },
      UpdateExpression:
        "set #HasResponse = :v_HasResponse, #ResponseTimeStamp = :v_ResponseTimeStamp, #Recommendation = :v_Recommendation, #ThreadRepComment = :v_ThreadRepComment",
      ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        "#HasResponse": payload.HasResponse,
        "#ResponseTimeStamp": payload.ResponseTimeStamp,
        "#Recommendation": payload.Recommendation,
        "#ThreadRepComment": payload.ThreadRepComment,
      },
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":v_HasResponse": payload.HasResponse,
        ":v_ResponseTimeStamp": payload.ResponseTimeStamp,
        ":v_Recommendation": payload.Recommendation,
        ":v_ThreadRepComment": payload.ThreadRepComment,
      },
      // returns only the affected attributes, as they appeared after the update
      ReturnValues: "UPDATED_NEW"
    };
```

I have printed out the payload.JobUID and payload.TimeStamp in the log so I know they are what expect.

The latest row in the table has JobUID and TimeStamp exactly as I printed them out.
I want to update the 4 properties in the expression attribute names.

I am getting the error "ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the schema"

I have looked on the web and in SOF at examples of updates and I cannot seem to get this to work.

what is wrong with my key values.

The update call looks like this.  Super simple

```
var returnValue = await dynamo.update(params).promise();
```

I also tried

```
Key: {
  JobUID: {"S": payload.JobUID},
  TimeStamp: {"S":payload.TimeStamp}
},
```

Comment: A epoch-format `TimeStamp` (`1649413120122`) would cause this error if you are not stringifying the value first.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @fedonev!  That was not the issue though

Comment: So here is what worked for me.  I needed to remove the quotes

Answer (score 0):

### So this is what I found works:

```
 var params = {
      TableName: tableName,
      Key: {
        JobUID: payload.JobUID,
        TimeStamp: payload.TimeStamp
      },
      UpdateExpression:
        "set HasResponse = :v_HasResponse, ResponseTimeStamp = :v_ResponseTimeStamp, Recommendation = :v_Recommendation, ThreadRepComment = :v_ThreadRepComment",
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":v_HasResponse": payload.HasResponse,
        ":v_ResponseTimeStamp": payload.ResponseTimeStamp,
        ":v_Recommendation": payload.Recommendation,
        ":v_ThreadRepComment": payload.ThreadRepComment || "",
      },
      // returns only the affected attributes, as they appeared after the update
      ReturnValues: "UPDATED_NEW"
    };

    var returnValue = await dynamo.update(params).promise();
```

If there is a property is is null or empty, in my case the ThreadRepComment could be null or empty so you need to handle that.